# Controller creation question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

in MVC.NET is a controller created once, or for each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on used `IControllerFactory` realization. But `DefaultControllerFactory` creates new controller instance for each request.

Answer (score 0):

The Controller is instantiated on each request.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/